# Braintree Authorize and capture android

Tags: android, braintree

Hi I need a procedure for payment, First I need to authorize a payment for certain amount let's say 10 and after few days I need to capture amount when the product has been delivered to user, and I can adjust the amount I mean can can capture 9 from the card.
How to do this braintree sdk.

Comment: You must have to generate nuance for authorise.

Comment: @Jason nuance will be valid for 3 hrs only

Comment: Right, for more info contact their support.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

When you make a [`transaction.sale` call](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale) in the Braintree API, you're actually only creating an [authorization](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/transactions/managing-authorizations). Once you're ready to capture the funds, you can use the `submit_for_settlement` to do so. That call includes a parameter named [`amount`, which allows you to control the amount you actually capture from the transaction](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/submit-for-settlement).

Say you created an authorization for a $10 charge. You could settle the transaction and capture only $9 like this:

```
result = Braintree::Transaction.submit_for_settlement("<transaction_id>", "9.00")
```

There are two restrictions to be aware of. First, you are only permitted to settle an amount equal to or less than the amount authorized. Second, the authorization will eventually expire after a period of time set by the card organization. Many groups will set their authorizations to expire after 7 days or 30 days. Once an authorization is expired, it cannot be settled.

If the authorizations expire too quickly for your business timeline, you can also [save the card in your vault](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create) and create the transaction later for a different amount.